# How bluemix resolves to Secure Gateway clients?

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

While using secure gateway to integrate bluemix and on-prem applications, we can use IBM client installer, Docker or DataPower.

For now, let us consider IBM client installer & Docker.

While configuring the client either through docker or by installing the client, we don't specify the details of the host on which the secure gateway client is running. We provide only the Gateway ID & Security Token. Want to understand how the resolution happens? In other words, how does bluemix connects to the gateway client to establish the connectivity to on-prem resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the other direction: The Secure Gateway (SG) client connect to the Bluemix environment. Thus, the administrator of the on-prem resources has full control. The client knows about where to connect to.

The [official documentation for the Secure Gateway](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SecureGateway/index.html#sg_overview) has more details.

Comment: Thanks so much. That was very helpful